# Is it possible to create a child theme of a child theme with Genesis in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Genesis Framework and then using a child theme for the genesis framework. Can I make a child theme to the child theme of the framework?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's a benefit of doing something like this? Are you planning on making multiple copies of a child theme, with minor changes here and there (for various purposes or audiences)?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea. I didn't know, but apparently, you can. From http://www.wp-code.com/wordpress-snippets/wordpress-grandchildren-themes/

> Instead of editing the child theme, create a grandchild theme. It’s
>   very similar to creating a child theme, except you do it via a plugin.
>   You add your custom functions to the plugin, just as you normally
>   would in functions.php (though remember your plugin will be called
>   much earlier than functions.php, so you’ll need to make sure that any
>   code in your plugin only runs when an action is fired).

```
/*
Plugin Name: Grandchild Theme
Plugin URI: http://www.wp-code.com/
Description: A WordPress Grandchild Theme (as a plugin)
Author: Mark Barnes
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://www.wp-code.com/
*/

// These two lines ensure that your CSS is loaded alongside the parent or child theme's CSS
add_action('wp_head', 'wpc_theme_add_headers', 0);
add_action('init', 'wpc_theme_add_css');

// This filter replaces a complete file from the parent theme or child theme with your file (in this case the archive page).
// Whenever the archive is requested, it will use YOUR archive.php instead of that of the parent or child theme.
add_filter ('archive_template', create_function ('', 'return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)."archive.php";'));

function wpc_theme_add_headers () {
    wp_enqueue_style('grandchild_style');
}

function wpc_theme_add_css() {
    $timestamp = @filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/style.css');
    wp_register_style ('grandchild_style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__).'', array(), $timestamp);
}

// In the rest of your plugin, add your normal actions and filters, just as you would in functions.php in a child theme.
```